# Moving an element from one dictionary to another

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dictionary

I have a dictionary with few pairs

```
Dictionary<DateTime, ObservableCollection<Car>>
```

and I'm changing year of production of a `Car`, and because `Key` (`DateTime`) is a year I need to move this `Car` from `KeyValuePair` with old year to `KeyValuePair` with new year.

so for example, I had two pairs:

```
1.1.1997 {Car1,Car2}
1.1.1998 {Car3}
```

and by

```
Car2.Production = Convert.ToDateTime("1.1.1998");
```

I need to have

```
1.1.1997 {Car1}
1.1.1998 {Car3,Car2}
```

What is the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: Not sure there are any *easy* ways to do that. You might want to re-think using a `DateTime` of production year as a `Key` in your `Dictionary`. If this were a database you'd have introduced a pretty nasty functional dependency.

Comment: I know that there is a code smell, but I haven't much time to refactor this. I need to work with that code.

Comment: Do you have access to the `Dictionary<DateTime, ObservableCollection<Car>>` in the code area where you're pulling out an individual `Car` to modify its `Production` value?

Comment: can you provide a working sample? these code fragments do not add up because the key is obviously not unique but the dictionary only works with unique keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you might want to use a grouped view for this data instead, but here's a code solution that addresses the question as stated. If you were planning on doing this for more than one property, I'd recommend making Car inherit from DependencyObject or implementing it from INotifyPropertyChanged instead of creating events for each.

```
// The car class itself
public class Car
{
    // This event is raised when the production property changes
    public event EventHandler<PropertyValueChange<DateTime>> ProductionChanged;
    DateTime _production; // private data
    public DateTime Production
    {
        get { return _production; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _production) return; // don't raise the event if it didn't change
            var eventArgs = new PropertyValueChange<DateTime>(_production, value);
            _production = value;
            // If anyone is "listening," raise the event
            if (ProductionChanged != null)
                ProductionChanged(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
}
// Class that contains the dictionary of production to car lists
class Foo
{
    Dictionary<DateTime, ObservableCollection<Car>> ProductionToCars = new Dictionary<DateTime, ObservableCollection<Car>>();

    public void Add(Car c)
    {
        _Add(c);
        // We want to be notified when the car's production changes
        c.ProductionChanged += this.OnCarProductionChanged;
    }
    // This is called when a car's value changes, and moves the car
    void OnCarProductionChanged(object sender, PropertyValueChange<DateTime> e)
    {
        Car c = sender as Car;
        if (c == null) return;
        ProductionToCars[e.OldValue].Remove(c);
        _Add(c);
    }
    // this actually places the car in the (currently correct) group
    private void _Add(Car c)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Car> collection;
        // Find the collection for this car's year
        if (!ProductionToCars.TryGetValue(c.Production, out collection))
        {
            // if we couldn't find it, create it
            collection = new ObservableCollection<Car>();
            ProductionToCars.Add(c.Production, collection);
        }
        // Now place him in the correct collection
        collection.Add(c);
    }

}
// This class encapsulates the information we'll pass when the property value changes
public class PropertyValueChange<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T OldValue;
    public T NewValue;
    public PropertyValueChange(T oldValue, T newValue)
    {
        OldValue = oldValue;
        NewValue = newValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work (not shortest code possible, but simple to understand):

```
private static void EnsureValuesAreCoherent(Dictionary<DateTime, ObservableCollection<Car>> param)
{
    List<Car> toMove = new List<Car>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, ObservableCollection<Car>> pair in param)
    {
        List<Car> toRemove = new List<Car>();
        foreach (Car car in pair.Value)
        {
            if (car.Production != pair.Key)
            {
                toRemove.Add(car);
            }
        }

        foreach (Car car in toRemove)
        {
            pair.Value.Remove(car);
            toMove.Add(car);
        }
    }

    foreach (Car car in toMove)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Car> currentCollection;
        if (param.TryGetValue(car.Production, out currentCollection))
        {
            currentCollection.Add(car);
        }
    }
}
```

But IMO it's a bad idea to have such a dependency between a key of a dictionary, and a member of the dictionary values.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to have a Dictionary in this case? If the requierment is you want to be able to operate on all cars of a particular production date, could you not use Linq?

```
ObservableCollection<Car> cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>();
var car1 = new Car() { Model = "Ford", ProductionDate = new DateTime(1997, 01, 01)} );
var car2 = new Car() { Model = "Chevy", ProductionDate = new DateTime(1997, 01, 01)} );
var car3 = new Car() { Model = "Ford", ProductionDate = new DateTime(2002, 01, 01)} );
cars.Add(car1);
cars.Add(car2);
cars.Add(car3);

var carsIn1997 = cars.Where(x => x.ProductionDate.Year == 1997);
var carsThatAreFords = cars.Where(x => x.Model == "Ford");
var groupedCars = cars.GroupBy(x => x.ProductionDate);
```

Using this method you can access all cars in a particular year, model etc... and manipulate the data, without worrying about moving references around etc...

For a general GroupBy tutorial, see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35667/How-to-Use-LINQ-GroupBy)